# A TIPS that matures in less than a month from now should trade like a treasury...Why can't I get the YTM's to match?

Tags: fixed-income, excel, inflation, treasuries

If a TIPS bond matures soon, lets say 4/15/24...we should know all the payments.  I would think that if we calculate the YTM on that after adjusting for inflation it should have the same YTM as a 4/15/24 Treasury.  But I am not getting there.

Using the cusip 9128286N5 which is a .5% 4/15/2024 TIPS.  These are my inputs into the Yield function:

```
Settlement = Today()
Maturity = 4/15/2024
Rate = .005
Price = 100.1719 (current market price)
Redemption = 122.64 (100 * 1.2264 adj. factor) (adj factor seen here: https://imgur.com/sTilx0x)
Frequency = 2
```

The output is 3.362%

Using the cusip 91282CBV2 which is a .375% 4/15/24 Treasury, these are the inputs to the Yield function:

```
Settlement = Today()
Maturity = 4/15/2024
Rate = .00375
Price = 99.707 (current market price)
Redemption = 100
Frequency = 2
```

The output is 4.78%

Shouldn't they be equal?  Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: I think the yield calculation is wrong in the case of the nominal Treasury.  Bloomberg says 5.4%.  For the tips, you might have made an input error.  price = quoted price * accrual factor , and redemption = 100* accrual factor at maturity, which is known.